# create dynamic time in php and mysql

Tags: php, recaptcha

i am first time using google ReCaptcha in website and download through [this link](https://github.com/google/ReCAPTCHA/tree/master/php).

google ReCaptcha working fine on my form but whenever user press the button form go other link. i need to make this google ReCaptcha required. please solve this.thanks

```html
<?php
require_once "recaptchalib.php";
$siteKey = "Site key";
$secret = "Secret key";
$lang = "en";
$resp = null;
$error = null;
$reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);
if(isset($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"])) {
    $resp = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
        $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
    );
}
?>
<html>
  <head><title>reCAPTCHA Example</title></head>
  <body>
<?php
if ($resp != null && $resp->success) {
    echo "You got it!";
}
?>
    <form method="post">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo $siteKey;?>"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=<?php echo $lang;?>"></script>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: i need to stop the page reload when user click the button till the recaptcha not filled or correct

Comment: If you have issues with reCAPTCHA your best ressource is the official recaptcha site. https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for display error msg for not correct captcha use link http://mycodde.blogspot.com/2014/12/new-checkbox-recaptcha-tutorial-with.html

Answer (score 0):

I think You are misconfiguration reCaptcha code, check below link and re setup your code

https://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/wiki/HowToSetUpRecaptcha#PHP